# Extra byte(s) after encoding/decoding

Tags: algorithm, encoding, byte, decoding, extra

I'm currently writing program to encode and decode messages via error-correcting cyclic codes. My algorithm works fine for single messages, but I got some problems in decoding strings. Encoding and decoding work like this:

1. Encoding algorithm receives *K* bit and as a result returns *N* bit.
2. Decoding algorithm receives *N* bit and as a result returns *K* bit.

For example, I want to encode and decode a string. I convert string to byte array and read it bit by bit, until K bit is read. Then I encode this *K* bit and write all *N* received bits bit by bit in byte array. And so on. Decoding is same, but I decode *N* bits and write *K* bits bit by bit in byte array. There is an example of my problem.

If K = 9 (Each line is length of *K* to visualize my problem)

> 0**][**11100000**]**
>  00**][**0011101
>   010**][**111000
>  0000**][**00111
>  11010**][**1110
>   111010**][**001
>  0111010**][**11
>   ***_*__*_*__*_*_****[**0

There is one zero in the last line, which didn't fit in the previous 9 bits. So I encode it like full *K* bit message. And of course after decoding I receive *K* bit message and extra byte appears.

> **[**00000000**][**0

And I don't know how to determine this extra byte. May be this zero byte was there before encoding.
Could you give me some advice what should I do with my problem. May be I should change my algorithm (may be I shouldn't read it bit by bit). I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to fill this gap with 0xFF byte. I use UTF8 encoding and it can't has 0xFF bytes, so I delete all 0xFF bytes at the end of the message after decoding.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding algorithms based on variable length of bits sequences are fairly common in the 'nature'. Check the solutions for [Bitwise IO](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitwise_IO) at the Rosetta Code, they may give you some idea.